# HMS Cordova HMS Map view blocks all the remaining UI

Tags: cordova, huawei-mobile-services

I have set up the map for HMSMap.js and following the link:
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/HMS-Plugin-Guides-V1/creating-a-map-0000001050204333-V1

The problem is that the cordova HMSMap should embed into the DOM div, but it doesn't, it just stay on top of all remaining UI and blocks all the view:

The screenshot of the result of HMSMap view:

[image: result of HMSMap view]

Any one has any idea?

Comment: Would you mind posting part of your code? It's easier if we could look at it :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all Huawei map can’t be embedded into a div because of the Cordova’s working mechanism. Map is drawing on the native java side on a different layout than Cordova web view because components can’t be added to web view. And then div’s position is been tracking to synchronize html div and the native map component.

So in this case if you try to put any html elements where map is standing it can’t be shown. Maybe the problem occurred because you are using positioned HTML elements and tried to draw a map that overlaps the elements. In this case you should decrease the height of the div or reposition the other elements.

To give more precise solution I need to see the code parts of the program.

Comment: Sorry Shirley for late reply, and thanks so much for your response.  I actually shifted the HMSMap native to HMSMap JS so now it works, but the thing is bit laggy compare to native map. About the native map, actually i wanted to know can that map be draw behind my DOM? instead of above all the DOM?

Comment: Bcz i use Ionic5/angular9, tried google native map and draw the google native map on the page section, it displayed behind my DOM, so when i slide my hamburger menu it will show the side-menu above my google native map, but hms native map, i dont see there is an option that could choose display above DOM or below DOM.

Comment: hi @Vincent kbkop,you can try to use the newest version,as relevant team confirmed,The issue you mentioned has been resolved in the latest version.

Comment: Oh thats cool! will try it out soon, thank u so much Shirley!

Comment: Hi Shirley, wanted to ask one more thing regarding the hms map, does hms map support tilted map properties and satellite map?

Comment: just to confirm,are u mean [tile overlay](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/tileoverlay-0000001050153293-V5?ha_source=hms1)?we are already support it now,but *satellite map* are not yet,according to the current product plan, will be available in Q1 2021. However, due to some uncontrollable factors, this time point may be updated.

Comment: I c, not tile overlay, i mean the tilted map, means slanted map, like the camera been slanted, like how u see the map in waze kinda feeling, then u see the road and building in 3d(from what i have in google map)

Comment: Hi@Vincent kbkop,According to relevant team confirmed, we do not support tilted map now. :( We'll let you know if it has any further information.